# ag-grid set filter with async options that are complex objects

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using the infinite rowModelType and am clearing and loaded new data every time the user changes a filter.

I have a field in my data which is a complex object called status with id and name properties. I am trying to load in async properties for the set filter but am getting some weird results. This is my coldef:

```
{
    headerName: 'Status',
    field: 'status',
    cellRenderer: (params) => params.value.name,
    keyCreator: (params) => params.value.id,
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
        newRowsAction: 'keep',
        values: (params) => this.statusApiService.getList().pipe(map(response => response.data)).subscribe(data => params.success(data)),
        cellRenderer: (params) => params.value.name
    }
}
```

The set filter is displaying correctly and so is the column e.g. the status names are showing both but when I click to deselect one of the items in the filter it deselects all.

Am I understanding the set filter. Can i use it and do my filtering server side? I don't want to do any client side comparators etc.

Comment: are you doing this.gridApi.setRowData(null); to clear the data? this will make the newRowsAction invalid

Comment: Not sure but unrelated to my actual issue I think. I am providing the values so set filter shouldn't be comparing the filters to the data available in the grid.

Comment: If you are clearing the data by providing null, the filters will reset

Comment: I am using a serverside datasource with a getRows method that calls the params.successCallback method with my new data.

Comment: @the-a-train, any luck, have you found a solution? i'm down with the same problem